# Use buffer overflow to print specific text

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   char a[5];
   char b[10];
   strcpy(a,"nop");
   gets(b);
   printf("Hello there %s. Value in a is %s.\n",b,a);
   exit(0);
}
```

I need to make the program print `Hello there Leslie. Value in a is Correct.`

I try to execute arbitrary input into the program, but I can't seem to make it ignore some input. For example if I run the program and enter:

```
Leslie\\\\Correct
```

The program will output `Hello there Leslie\\\\Correct. Value in a is Correct.` How can I remove the `\\\\Correct` from the first part using buffer overflow?

Comment: So, you are trying to *use* buffer overflow? That's why you are using `gets`?

Comment: @YuHao Yes, to print that specific text. Apparently I must overwrite an address but I don't know how here.

Comment: Simple answer: don't do that. Don't use `gets`, don't *use* buffer overflow.

Comment: @YuHao I'm not asking for advice, I want to solve the problem.

Comment: you use fgets for read the line

Comment: the results of caused the overflow behavior is undefined.

Comment: You are busy tonight @Jason. Take a look at [**Stack Smashing On A Modern Linux System**](http://www.exploit-db.com/papers/24085/). You can google on **stack smashing exploit** to turn up several more papers along with sample code.

Answer (score 3):

`%s` looks for a null termination character i.e '\0' in order to know when the string ends. So you need to enter "Leslie\0---Correct" to get your desired format. gets will add another `\0` at the end of the input so you need to remember that to not really cause a BO... 
Sorry for the bad format, I'm on my phone.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get the same result (the \0-- is included in the first string).

Comment: @Jason You shouldn't input "\0" directly, but input a null character.

Comment: @user4098326 How can I do that? I've tried Leslie\x90 Correct and Leslie\x00 Correct and neither work.

Comment: The null-terminating character `'\0'` has decimal value `0`. So just write `0`'s to those memory locations.

Answer (score 0):

This is about typing the `null` character in your terminal.
The following works on my machine (although I had to change the code to have `b` stored in a lower address than `a`), but let's assume that your code works:

```
./bufferovfl
Leslie(press ctrl+@)AAAAACorrect
       |.........|  |...|
            |         |
       the Null      any characters but with right repetition to overwrite [a] 
       character     starting with the C
```

Adding the null character at the end of `Leslie`, the function `gets` will store only that part in the variable `b` but will continue to write the addresses next and eventually overwrite variable `a`.

You may also want to check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character#Representation) article, if this combination(`ctrl`+`@`) fails.